# JOGL sample code compile error "cannot access WriteCloneable"

Tags: java, compilation, jogl

I get JOGL library form jogamp.org and extract
Directory structure is not changed
I write sample code as below

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.WindowAdapter;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.WindowEvent;
import com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator;

public class FirstStepNewt implements GLEventListener { //(1)
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FirstStepNewt();
    }
    
    public FirstStepNewt() {
    GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2));//(2)
    GLWindow glWindow = GLWindow.create(caps); //(3)
    glWindow.setTitle("First demo (Newt)"); //(4)
    glWindow.setSize(300, 300); //(5)

type here
```

and compile
then error occur at GLWindow.create
error message is cannot acceess WriteCloneable
how can I solve this problem

I check classpath
I consult JOGL api but word WriteCloneable is not found

Comment: At first, rather post your JOGL specific questions on our official forum https://forum.jogamp.org as a very few contributors are active on StackOverflow. Secondly, JOGL depends on GlueGen, WriteCloneable comes from GlueGen. Either use JogAmp fat JAR or use both JOGL and GlueGen JARs to compile and run your program.

Comment: I advise you to follow our instructions in our wiki: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Compile_and_run_your_project_from_the_command_line As you can see, both GlueGen and JOGL must be in the classpath. Is gluegen-rt in your classpath?

Comment: Thank you for your advice gouessej .   I go to forum.jogamp and post my question.